# How to read values from .ini file with GetPrivateProfileStringW

Tags: c#, .net, ini

I want to get data from my ini file, which looks like this:

```
[UI]
visibility=hidden
size=medium
```

with the following code:

```
string section = "UI";
string key = "size";
string defaultValue "-";

string value = GetValueFromIni(section, key, defaultValue);

-----------------------------------------------------------------

this.filePath = @"C:\Users\00372\test.ini";

public string GetValueFromIni(string section, string key, string defaultValue = "")
{
    string value = string.Empty;
    int i = GetPrivateProfileStringW(section, key, defaultValue, value, 255, this.filePath);
    return value ?? defaultValue;
}

[DllImport("kernel32")]
private static extern int GetPrivateProfileStringW(string section, string key, string defaultValue, string value, int size, string filePath);
```

But it won't work.

I am always getting the default value.

Does anyone know a solution to this?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the very least, your p/invoke signature is wrong.

`lpReturnedString` is a pointer to a buffer into which the result should be written. C# strings are immutable, so the marshaller isn't going to mutate your `value` variable. Instead, you should use a `StringBuilder`:

```
[DllImport("kernel32")]
private static extern int GetPrivateProfileString(
    string section,
    string key,
    string defaultValue,
    StringBuilder value,
    int size,
    string filePath);
```

Call it with e.g.

```
var value = new StringBuilder(255);
int ret = GetPrivateProfileString(section, key, defaultValue, value, value.Capacity, this.filePath);
// TODO: Check 'ret'
return value.ToString();
```

It's always worth checking http://pinvoke.net for inspiration, although take the signatures there with a grain of salt.

I haven't tested this with your input, so I can't guarantee that it works. If someone else comes up with the full solution, please accept their answer over mine.

Comment: Thanks, but this does not give me the value either. Value is just an empty string.

Comment: Oh well, it's at least *part* of the problem. Updated to clarify.

Comment: What value are you seeing for `ret`?

Comment: Nevermind, I forgot to remove the "W" from GetPrivateProfileStringW. It works now :)

Comment: Yeah, the marshaller's good to choosing the right A/W variant